# BroadcastReceiver ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED never received

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a service with a `BroadcastReceiver` on the `ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED` action. The service is started at boot and keeps running, and I have an activity that allows me to check the service is running and start/stop it. I don't receive any intent when connecting/disconnecting to/from a bluetooth device. I am testing this on a HTC Desire S running Android 2.3. I tried to register the `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest but to no avail.

Here is the code :

```
public class BTDetectSrv  extends Service {
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() 
{               
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    IntentFilter filter1, filter2, filter3, filter4;
    filter1 = new IntentFilter("android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED");
    filter2 = new IntentFilter(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    filter3 = new IntentFilter(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    filter4 = new IntentFilter(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter2);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter3);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter4);
    return START_STICKY;
}

//The BroadcastReceiver that listens for bluetooth broadcasts
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        Toast.makeText(BlueDetectSrv.this, "BT change received !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            Toast.makeText(BlueDetectSrv.this, device.getName() + " Device found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Toast.makeText(BlueDetectSrv.this, device.getName() + " Device is now connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
            Toast.makeText(BlueDetectSrv.this, device.getName() + " Device is about to disconnect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Toast.makeText(BlueDetectSrv.this, device.getName() + " Device has disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }           
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    Toast.makeText(this, "BlueDetect Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

I added the following permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: do you have the bluetooth permissions set ?

Comment: I forgot bluetooth permission. I works fine now. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

As per the user comment, He missed adding Bluetooth Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```